# Como aplicar a estratégia DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) nesse código?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Tenho várias tabelas, uma em cada página da minha aplicação e todas terão a mesma função de filtrar uma coluna, porém as colunas tem nomes diferentes e ordens diferentes.

Como escrever esse código sem que ficasse repetitivo?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    // Filtro da tabela em fila
    var em_fila = $('#em_fila').dataTable({
                        "sDom":     "t",
                        "paging":   false,
                        "ordering": false,
                        "info":     false
                      }
                  );

    $('.select-category').change( function () { 
        em_fila.fnFilter($('.select-category').val(), 0);
    }); 

    // Filtro da tabela digitação
    var em_digitacao = $('#em_digitacao').dataTable({
                               "sDom":     "t",
                               "paging":   false,
                               "ordering": false,
                               "info":     false
                           }
                       );

    $('.select-category').change( function () { 
        em_digitacao.fnFilter($('.select-category').val(), 0);
    }); 

    // Filtro da tabela com erros
    var com_erros = $('#com_erros').dataTable({
                            "sDom":     "t",
                            "paging":   false,
                            "ordering": false,
                            "info":     false
                        }
                    );

    $('.select-category').change( function () { 
        com_erros.fnFilter($('.select-category').val(), 0);
    });

    // Filtro da tabela com em_recebimentos
    var em_recebimentos = $('#em_recebimentos').dataTable({
                                  "sDom":     "t",
                                  "paging":   false,
                                  "ordering": false,
                                  "info":     false
                              }
                          );

    $('.select-category').change( function () { 
        em_recebimentos.fnFilter($('.select-category').val(), 0);
    });           

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Olá!

Primeiramente ajudará bastante a identação do código.
Bom, você está utilizando repetidamente o datatable com configurações padrão. Você poderia fazer o seguinte. Nas tabelas que você utiliza, no html, você adiciona uma classe chamada '**datatable-defaults**' (ou algo que remeta que isto é um datatables com esses ajustes padrão.

No seu código, faça o seguinte:

```
$('table[class~=datatable-defaults]').dataTable(
    {"sDom":"t",
     "paging":   false,
     "ordering": false,
     "info":     false
});
```

Isso fará com que todas aquelas tabelas que você precisa para tal já serão instanciadas com o datatable. O segredo está na query da DOM. No trecho:

```
table[class~=datatable-defaults]
```

Ele buscará qualquer "table" que tenha, dentro do atributo class, o texto **datatable-defaults**.

Ou seja,

```
(...)
<table id="em_recebimentos" class="table-teste um-estilo-css datatable-defaults">
(...)
```

...será encontrado através da query do Jquery, logo sendo submetido ao inicializador do **datatables**, por exemplo.

Documentação desse método: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Espero ter ajudado! =)

Comment: Porque você complicou tanto o seletor? Um simples `table.datatable-defaults` daria o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando a mesma configuração para todas as tabelas. Portanto, você pode simplificar selecionando todas as tabelas de uma só vez.

```
var tables = $('#em_fila, #em_digitacao, #com_erros, #em_recebimentos').dataTable({
        "sDom":     "t",
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false
    }
);

$('.select-category').change( function () { 
    tables.fnFilter($('.select-category').val(), 0);
});
```

Comment: Gostei do avatar!